# .serialize() not returning values from dynamically generated form

Tags: jquery, serialization

I'm missing something here.

I have a form dynamically loading a form using jquery where .click() pulls in a $.post query that outputs the form with some specific data to .html().

I'm now trying to serialize the data from this form and it's not giving me anything. What am I doing wrong?

Code inserting form:

```
$(".edit").click(function(){
    var mid = $(this).attr("uid");
    $.post("inc/menu_mod.php", { page: "edit",menu_id: mid, sender: 'sent'}, function(data){
    $('#menu_mod').html(data);
    });             

    });
```

My attempt to serialize:

```
    $(".update_menu").live('click', function(){
        alert("this fires, so I know it's working");
        var form = $('#menu_form form').serialize();
        alert(form);

    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your selector should be `var form = $('#menu_form').serialize();` because `menu_form` is the `id` of the form.